# Is nil a possible output in this problem?

Tags: list, scheme

I know `cddar` means the *second* of the *second* of the *first* in the list but there is no second one for `2`. Does this mean that the second one of `2` is a `nil` since there isn't one or did I do this problem wrong or does it output `2`?

```lisp
(cddar '((1 2) 3 (4 5)))
```

Comment: No, it's the rest (i.e. the tail) of the rest of the first element. The second of the second of the first would be `cadadar`.

Comment: @molbdnilo To be clearer, the `cdr` is the second element of a *pair*; the `cadr` is the second element of a *list*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cddar` is the same as `cdr` of `cdr` of `car`, so let's look how it evaluates step by step:

```lisp
(cdr (cdr (car '((1 2) 3 (4 5))))) =>

(cdr (cdr '(1 2))) =>

(cdr '(2)) =>

'()
```

So **yes**, `nil`/`()` is the result of `(cddar '((1 2) 3 (4 5)))`. And **no**, it's not `(cdr 2)`.

It's because every proper list ends with `nil` in the second slot of the *cons cell*:

```lisp
(cons 2 '()) =>

(2)
```

so `(2)` is a *list* of one element. It has `2` in first slot of *cons cell* and `()` in second. That's why `(cdr '(2))` is `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the pairs... Here they are:

```
(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 '()))
      (cons 3
            (cons (cons 4 (cons 5 '()))
                  '())))
```

Or in dot notation:

```
'((1 . (2 . ())) . (3 . ((4 . (5 . ())) . ())))
```

When I see `((1 2) 3 (4 5))` I see the invisible dots and extra parentheses that are missing in the representation. The simplification that if the part after a `.` is a pair you can just omit the dot and one set of parentheses on the `cdr`. Scheme will only display dot when there is no parenteses on the `cdr` to remove eg. like `'(4 . 5)` is always printed like that while `'(4 . (5 . ()))` is always simplified to `'(4 5)` in printing. As long as you don't get that you will have a hard problems with lists since lists are imaginary! Pairs are the real data structure.

You want to apply `cddar`. You just do the `d` and `a` from right to left. Thus you want `car`, then `cdr`, then `cdr`. With `car` you pick the left side of the dot and with `cdr` you pick the right side. Lets do it on `((1 . (2 . ())) . (3 . ((4 . (5 . ())) . ())))`.

1. init  => `((1 . (2 . ())) . (3 . ((4 . (5 . ())) . ())))`
2. `car` => `(1 . (2 . ()))`
3. `cdr` => `(2 . ())`
4. `cdr` => `()`